# Proof that $\mathrm{Aut}(K\left[ \sqrt[m]{g \in K} \right])/\mathrm{Aut}(K) = \mathbb{Z}_w, w | g $

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K$ be an extension field of $\mathbb{Q}$. That is

$$ K = \mathbb{Q}[r_1,\ldots,r_k ]$$

I am considering $\mathrm{Aut}(K)$ which is the group of field automorphisms of $K$ and I wish to show that given $K[\sqrt[m]g]$ for some $g \in K$ that:

$$\mathrm{Aut}(K[\sqrt[m]g])/\mathrm{Aut}(K) = \mathbb{Z}_w$$

where $w | g$.

### Work So Far:

My first observation is that if

$$\mathrm{Aut}(K[\sqrt[m]g])/\mathrm{Aut}(K) = \mathbb{Z}_w$$

Then I'm really looking at:

$$\mathrm{Aut} \left( K\left[\sqrt[w]{g^{\frac{w}{m}}}\right] \right)/\mathrm{Aut}(K) = \mathbb{Z}_w$$

Such that $g^{\frac{w}{m}}$ doesn't have any "roots" of its own in $K$ (I have intuition but no decisive rigorous reasoning that: $g^{\frac{w}{m}} \in K$ if: $\mathrm{Aut}(K[\sqrt[m]g])/\mathrm{Aut}(K) = \mathbb{Z}_w$)

We return noting that:

$$g^{\frac{1}{b}\frac{w}{m}} \not\in K, b \in \mathbb{N}, b \ne 1$$

So the question is given an element $u$ such that $u^{\frac{1}{b}} \not\in K, b \ne 1, b \in \mathbb{N}$ how can I show that

$$ \mathrm{Aut}(K[ \sqrt[w]{u}])/\mathrm{Aut}(K) = \mathbb{Z}_w$$

Observe that every element in $K[ \sqrt[w]{u}]$will be of the form

$$ s_0 + s_1\sqrt[w]{u}+ s_2 \sqrt[w]{u^2} + ... s_{w-1} \sqrt[w]{u^{w-1}}, s_i \in K$$

From there consider maps $m_i: \forall \  j \  s_j \sqrt[w]{u^j} \rightarrow e_i^j s_j \sqrt[w]{u^j} $ where $e_i$ is the $i^{th}$ w-root of unity. It's easy to see that these are all automorphisms and they form the group $\mathbb{Z}_w$ under composition.

So what remains to be shown is that NO other automorphisms exist.

Comment: I’m somewhat at sea on this one. Is $K$ to be an algebraic extension of $\Bbb Q$? If so, you’d better specify that. And you’re not assuming that $m$-th roots of unity are in $K$, right?

Comment: I'm assuming the $m-th$ roots are in $K$ and $K$ is an algebraic extension

Comment: Very good. But you should be thinking of the automorphisms of $K$ not as a subgroup of the automorphisms of $K(\sqrt[m]g\,)$ but as a quotient of that bigger group.